# How to get SHA of the latest commit from remote git repository?

Tags: git

Does anyone know how to get the latest SHA of a given branch **from outside** a git repository?

If you are inside a git repository, you can do:

```
git log origin/branch_X | head -1
```

However, I am not inside a git repository, and I would like to avoid having to `clone` a repository just to get the latest SHA of a tag/branch. Is there a clever way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have filesystem access to the repository you would like to query?

Comment: The correct way to do this is "git rev-parse origin/branch_X" or "git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/branch_X", not git-log

Comment: What about doing this without having the repo cloned but having the url I could use to clone it? (To answer my own Q: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24750310/7945066)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you want to check SHA-1 of given branch in remote repository, then [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161869/in-git-how-to-get-sha-of-the-latest-commit-from-outside-the-repository/1161926#1161926) is correct:

```
$ git ls-remote <URL>
```

However if you are on the same filesystem simpler solution (not requiring to extract SHA-1 from output) would be simply:

```
$ git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git rev-parse origin/branch_X
```

See [git(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) manpage for description of '`--git-dir`' option.

Answer (score 130):

Use [rev-parse](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)

```
git rev-parse origin/master # to get the latest commit on the remote

git rev-parse HEAD          # to get the latest commit on the local
```

Comment: +1 Proved most useful along with appending | clip to drop the sha onto the clipboard (windows).

Comment: And for those mac users `git rev-parse origin/master | pbcopy` will drop the commit sha (with a `\n`) on your clipboard for you to paste at your convenience.

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` returns the latest commit in the local copy, while `git rev-parse origin/master` returns the latest commit on remote, which is what's been asked here. This is my favorite answer, even if first command should be removed.

Comment: The question notes "I would like to avoid having to clone a repository just to get the latest SHA of a tag/branch". Is it possible to use `git rev-parse` against a repository that you don't have any information for locally?

Comment: I think git rev-parse origin/master only returns the correct answer if your local repo is up to date.  To prove this, disconnect from the internet and try it; the command will succeed.  In contrast, git ls-remote will fail because it tries to contact the remote repo.

Comment: Found this to be very useful if you only want to grab a specific branch such as master ```git rev-parse REMOTE_NAME BRANCH_NAME```

Comment: uhhh, no, it's `git fetch origin; git rev-parse origin/master`, isn't the fetch extremely important?

Answer (score 59):

A colleague of mine answered this for me:

```
git ls-remote ssh://git.dev.pages/opt/git/repos/dev.git <branch>
```

Comment: thanks. This should be upgraded as answer for this question.

Answer (score 23):

Using a git URL:

```
$ git ls-remote <URL> | head -1 | sed "s/HEAD//"
```

Using a directory on an accessible system:

```
$ git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git rev-parse origin/<targeted-banch>
```

Comment: Use `sed "s/\tHEAD//"` to also remove the trailing tab.

Comment: Why not using `| awk '{ print $1 }'`?

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in comments above this should be the best solution:

`$ git ls-remote <URL> | head -1 | cut -f 1`

Comment: This is the only option that worked (for me) for getting the commit from an upstream remote in a forked repo.

Answer (score 15):

This should do the trick `git ls-remote REMOTE | awk "/BRANCH/ {print \$1}"`

Replace REMOTE with the name of the remote repository and BRANCH with the name of the branch.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the SHA-1 from the currently checked out branch of your local repo, you can just specify HEAD instead of origin/branch_X:

`git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git rev-parse --verify HEAD`

Answer (score 4):

Heres a copy-paste solution which works inside the repository.

```
origin_head=$(git ls-remote --heads $(git config --get remote.origin.url) | grep "refs/heads/master" | cut -f 1)
if [ $origin_head != "$(git rev-parse HEAD)" ]; then
    echo >&2 "HEAD and origin/master differ."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I would recommend `grep "refs/heads/master$"` so if anyone might asked for other branches than master or having an master2 branch this may break ;)

Answer (score 2):

References to branch heads are stored in the `.git/refs/` tree. So you should be able to find the hash of the latest commit at:

```
cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/branch_X
```

Your path may differ slightly.

Comment: That wouldn't work if you have packed refs. Then you have to take a look at  .git/packed-refs

Comment: That's true, this solution is susceptible to any future changes in the Git on-disk repository format.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the `--short` parameter to `rev-parse` removes the need for parsing the response via awk etc.

```
git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD
```

(from the repo root dir; examples above show how to use `--git-dir` and variants to reference other directories).

…produces just the sha to 7 digits (or however many you indicate):

> 5efca96

Answer (score 0):

I recommend fetching info related only to a given branch, and then parse to get the latest sha:
`git ls-remote <url> --tags <branch_name> | awk '{print $1;}'`