# github api get SHA of master

Tags: api, github

Im looking for the SHA of the current master of a github repo.

If I do something like this:
    https://api.github.com/repos/ameyer/Arduino-L6470/git/trees/master

The returned SHA is 'master'.

I need a way to check if the version of the master on github is newer than what I have in a cached app, and I figured the SHA would be the best way to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try fetching the references:

https://api.github.com/repos/ameyer/Arduino-L6470/git/refs

And then you can:

https://api.github.com/repos/ameyer/Arduino-L6470/git/trees/d0cad097e733c3d9b7051c6f047411c5e3494491

Notice that this second URL gives basically the same result as the URL you tried, only the `master` ref name is replaced with the actual sha of the latest commit.

So, basically, just fetch the refs and get the sha of master.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind launching a process you can also use "native" git api:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/ameyer/Arduino-L6470 master
```

That would also work for other hosting providers and across http api changes.

original source: [How to get SHA of the latest commit from remote git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1161926/6040478)