# Is it possible to get commits history for one file in github api?

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to get all commit messages for separate file in github REST api. But all I got - only to get all commits for separate branch. Then I tried to get following:

```
http://api.github.com/users/<username>/<project>/commits/<branch>/<path/to/file>
```

But that didn't help also. Is this at least possible?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this (as described in the API docs [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository)):

http://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?path=PATH_TO_FILE

e.g.

https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/commits?path=README.markdown

---

**Extra:** Get commits history for one file **from a specific branch**

- (1) Get Branch [SHA hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13931146/4861760):

  - Syntax: https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs
  - Example: `https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/git/refs`
  - Grab the `object.sha` for a specific branch, e.g. `refs/heads/gh-pages`
- (2) Make the request using the extra `sha=BRANCH_HASH` parameter:

  - Syntax: https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?sha=BRANCH_HASH&path=PATH_TO_FILE
  - Example: `https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/commits?sha=0a8e26a92ee3101803314ee7dea6c6057ff2b862&path=apidocs.markdown`

Comment: what about the branch here ?

Comment: Wer lesen kann, ist klar im Vorteil ;). https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#parameters

Comment: @SameerSawla `https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits?sha={branch}&path={path}`

Answer (score 10):

Using [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), for a file on the default branch, it would be :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "izuzak", name: "pmrpc") {
    defaultBranchRef{
      target {
        ...on Commit{
            history(first:100,path: "README.markdown"){
            nodes {
              author {
                email
              }
              message
              oid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?variables=%7B%7D&query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22izuzak%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22pmrpc%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20defaultBranchRef%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...on%20Commit%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A100%2Cpath%3A%20%22README.markdown%22)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)