# 'git ls-remote' command parameter to limit the number of returned rows

Tags: git

We can use `git ls-remote` command to get the list of commits of a given git repo e.g. [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162373/248616)

This command takes us quite a long time for the repo that has big list of commits/tags - we are looking for a parameter for it and/or any other command to limit the number of returned rows e.g. only read the first 3 rows in the returned list.

How can we get to that?

p.s.

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=%27git+ls-remote%27+command+parameter+to+limit+the+number+of+returned+rows&oq=%27git+ls-remote%27+command+parameter+to+limit+the+number+of+returned+rows&aqs=chrome..69i57.211j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [our site search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%27git+ls-remote%27+command+parameter+to+limit+the+number+of+returned+rows+) is little helpful.

Comment: After posting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45253629/6394138) I figured out that if you are comfortable with receiving an incomplete list, then maybe you are trying to solve some problem you don't tell us about with the wrong tool. Can you tell exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: One usecase @Leon, we want to get the latest commit/tag row as fast as we can

Comment: Do you mean the *latest commit on a given branch*?

Comment: Right @Leon in the fastest time

Comment: I thought that `git fetch --dry-run` *`remote branch`* might work for you, but studying the code revealed that it uses `transport_get_remote_refs()` (i.e. the core of `git ls-remote`) underneath.

Comment: You are really really good in git knowledge. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See updated answer. Bottom line is that it is possible only if the remote supports the dumb protocol.

Comment: I'm using github repo. How to verify if dump protocol is supported or not?

Comment: GitHub doesn't support the dumb protocol, but instead it provides a rich API, with possibility to [Get a Reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-a-reference), for example: `curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/dictcp/awesome-git/git/refs/heads/master|grep '^ *"sha":'`

Comment: Great thanks! Absolutely I'll try github API someday - currently just accept the slow speed over here then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git ls-remote` works by [fetching the full list of refs from the remote and then filtering it locally](https://github.com/git/git/blob/117ddefdb4dfd9b40ae60967a7327754d8ce7a87/builtin/ls-remote.c#L99):

```c++
int cmd_ls_remote(int argc, const char **argv, const char *prefix)
{
   ...

    transport = transport_get(remote, NULL);
    if (uploadpack != NULL)
        transport_set_option(transport, TRANS_OPT_UPLOADPACK, uploadpack);

/* Get all refs from the remote */
    ref = transport_get_remote_refs(transport);
    if (transport_disconnect(transport))
        return 1;

    if (!dest && !quiet)
        fprintf(stderr, "From %s\n", *remote->url);

/* Filter the list of all refs */
    for ( ; ref; ref = ref->next) {
        if (!check_ref_type(ref, flags))
            continue;
        if (!tail_match(pattern, ref->name))
            continue;
        if (show_symref_target && ref->symref)
            printf("ref: %s\t%s\n", ref->symref, ref->name);
        printf("%s\t%s\n", oid_to_hex(&ref->old_oid), ref->name);
        status = 0; /* we found something */
    }
    return status;
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to [this page, explaining git transfer protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols), if the remote supports the dumb protocol, then you can obtain the remote `refs/heads/branchname` file directly (e.g. using `curl`).

> ### The Dumb Protocol
>
> If you’re setting up a repository to be served read-only over HTTP, the dumb protocol is likely what will be used. This protocol is called “dumb” because it requires no Git-specific code on the server side during the transport process; the fetch process is a series of HTTP GET requests, where the client can assume the layout of the Git repository on the server.
>
> ...

Otherwise, when the smart protocol is utilized, the first piece of data sent from a remote  is always the list of all remote references, i.e. any git command connecting to a remote via the smart protocol acts as if `git ls-remote` is run internally (more technically, all such commands call the [`transport_get_remote_refs()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e629a7d28a405e48fae6b064a781a10e885159fc/transport.c#L1099) function). In that case, unfortunately, there is no way to speed-up your query, not even a workaround.

> ### The Smart Protocol
>
> ...
>
> #### Uploading Data
>
> To upload data to a remote process, Git uses the `send-pack` and `receive-pack` processes. The `send-pack` process runs on the client and connects to a `receive-pack` process on the remote side.
>
> ...
>
> **The `git-receive-pack` command immediately responds with one line for
>   each reference it currently has**.
>
> ...
>
> #### Downloading Data
>
> When you download data, the `fetch-pack` and `upload-pack` processes
>   are involved. The client initiates a `fetch-pack` process that
>   connects to an `upload-pack` process on the remote side to negotiate
>   what data will be transferred down.
>
> ...
>
> After `fetch-pack` connects, `upload-pack` sends back something like
>   this: ... **This is very similar to what `receive-pack` responds with, but
>   the capabilities are different** (*i.e. the list of all refs + some
>   additional data*).
>
> ...